# ScrollView can scroll but the height of child not enough to cause it scroll

Tags: android

below is my layout：

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="0.5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <ViewAnimator
        android:id="@+id/animator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="18dp"
                android:text="content"
                android:textColor="#999"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="26dp"
                android:text="details"
                android:textColor="#999"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <include layout="@layout/divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/shop_receive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="shop receive"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/shop_receive_radio"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_radio"
                    android:button="@null" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/send_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="send post"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/send_post_radio"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_radio"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:checked="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/divider" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                style="@style/ButtonTheme"
                android:text="next" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/send_post_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout="@layout/layout_send_post" />

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/shop_receive_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout="@layout/layout_shop_receive" />
    </ViewAnimator>
</ScrollView>
```

below is my code:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sendPostRadio.isChecked()) {
                initSendPostLayout();  //init the first viewstub and show it
                animator.setDisplayedChild(1);
            }

            if (shopReceiveRadio.isChecked()) {
                initShopReceiveLayout(); //init the second viewstub and show
                animator.setDisplayedChild(2);
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode) {
        int child = animator.getDisplayedChild();
        if (0 == child) {
            finish();
        } else {
            animator.setDisplayedChild(0);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

below is the layout of layout_shop_receive：

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="34dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:text="领取地址" />

<XListView
    android:id="@+id/receive_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

below is the class XListView：

```
public class XListView extends ListView {

public XListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public XListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public XListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int measureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, measureSpec);
}
```

}

When display shop receive layout,the height of the listview is big enough that the scrollview can scroll，but when I press back to display the first child of viewanimator, the scrollview still can scroll,however the first child of viewanimator's height is small that one screen can hold all the first child，why scrollview can still scroll?